# How to get just one attribute value out of json string

Tags: json, python-3.x

i am pretty new to python and i tried some things but can't seem to find the solution for this.
I am making a get request to a ldap local server and the response is a list, i don't know if this is a list of lists or just a list.

```
[
  "cn=Philip J. Fry,ou=people,dc=planetexpress,dc=com", 
  "cn=Turanga Leela,ou=people,dc=planetexpress,dc=com", 
  "cn=Bender Bending Rodr\u00edguez,ou=people,dc=planetexpress,dc=com"
]
```

I want to return a json with only the "cn" values. 
Like this:

```
[
  "Philip", 
  "Turanga", 
  "Bender"
]
```

Thanks for the help

Comment: Share the code you have currently. Also, share the original response of the server. This doesn't like like JSON to me.

Comment: Technically that is a JSON list but each element is just string. You will need to use several `.split(...)`s to get what you want. Split on a comma then split on a space. If you want a more detailed answer if may help to show the code you got and the fulle response.

Comment: thanks i did it with the split, was easier in my case.

Answer (score 1):

I would convert the strings into dictionaries:

```
def ldap_to_dict(string):
    d = {}
    for pair in string.split(","):
        key, val = pair.split("=")
        if key in d:  # handle multiple value case
            if isinstance(d[key], list):
                d[key].append(val)
            else:
                d[key] = [d[key], val]
        else:
            d[key] = val
    return d

names = [ldap_to_dict(ldap_string)["cn"] for ldap_string in original_list]
```

Aftermath:

```
>>> names
['Philip J. Fry', 'Turanga Leela', 'Bender Bending Rodríguez']
```

Comment: Thanks for the fast response i manage to do it with splits only, but now i can't return  it as json to a route.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks guys for the quick responses.
I manage to do it like this:

```
list1 = []
list2 = []
list3 = []


@app.route('/users', methods=['GET'])
def list_users():

    string = (ldap.get_group_members('ship_crew'))

    for user in string:
        list1.append(user.split(",")[0])
        a = list1
    for user in a:
        list2.append(user.split("=")[1])
        b = list2
    for user in b:
        list3.append(user.split(" ")[0])

    return jsonify(list3)
```

Output:

```
['Philip', 'Turanga', 'Bender']
```

But now when i'am trying to return it as json with this command:

```
curl -X GET -H "Content-type: application/json charset=UTF-8" -H "Accept: application/json"  http://localhost:5000/users
```

I get:

```
TypeError: a bytes-like object is required, not 'str'
```

Even if i json.dump my list3 and get:

```
["Philip", "Turanga", "Bender"]
```

I got the same error.

I'am getting my string from a ldap.

What's the problem here?
Thanks